# How do I define/set an attribute in a FactoryGirl factory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, alias, factory

I’m using Rails 4.2, Ruby 2.3.8, and factory girl 4.5.0. I have this model with an aliased attribute

```
class User
  include ActiveModel::Model
    …

  alias customer_name full_name
end
```

I have this corresponding FactoryGirl factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    id { rand(83800..83999) }
    …
    full_name “My “name
    customer_name { full_name }
    …

    skip_create
    initialize_with { new(attributes) }
  end
end
```

From another factory, I run

```
   user: create(:user)
```

But then I get this error

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `customer_name=' for #<User:0x0000000009f0fd58>
   Did you mean?  customer_name
```

Complaining about the

```
initialize_with { new(attributes) }
```

Line of the user factory.  What’s the right way to define an aliased attribute in a factory?

Comment: I think the problem is in your model. `alias customer_name full_name` is OK, but you would also need to define a `#customer_name=` method (the assignment method)

Answer (score 0):

An alias only creates a reader method but no writer method.

Try to add a writer as well

```
alias :customer_name= :full_name=
```